# SQL server Reporting services with Classic ASP

Tags: reporting-services, asp-classic

I have an application in **Classic Asp**, and I'm in need to use **SQL Server Reporting Services**. The page that will generate the report have some filters and I have to use it.

I already made the **Stored Procedure** and the SSRS solution. I just wanna know how to call the report in the Classic ASP.

Thank you.

Comment: In ASP.NET I call the report like that: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "t", "abrirRelatorio('" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"].ToString() + "rel_ficha&fic_codigo=" + objStr.ToString() + "&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs:ClearSession=true&rs%3aFormat=pdf&rc%3aToolbar=False&rc%3aJavaScript=False&rc%3aLinkTarget=_top&rc%3aArea=Params');", true);

Comment: do you have a function called 'abrirRelatorio' in your page ? I think you will have to add a script block to the page to add that function. the report server value can be got from the web.config and the rest of the values can be used as such .. and you will have to bind this function to an onclick of a button or a link .. How were you doing this in .net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researching I found my solution.
I used the event onClick in the input button, calling a function.
See the code bellow:

"
        function report() {

```
        var vexp_expediente = document.getElementById('txtexp_num_exp').value;
        var vpro_obs = document.getElementById('txtpro_obs').value;
        var vsit_id = document.getElementById('sit_id').value;
        var vpro_numero = document.getElementById('txtpro_numero').value;
        var vexp_requisitante = document.getElementById('txtexp_requisitante').value;
        var vexp_num_req = document.getElementById('txtexp_num_req').value;
        var vlic_id = document.getElementById('lic_id').value;
        var vare_id = document.getElementById('cboare_id').value;

        window.open("http://Report-Server/ReportServer?%2fSCPC%2fRel_Processos_Compra&exp_num_exp=" + vexp_expediente + "&pro_obs=" + vpro_obs + "&sit_id=" + vsit_id + "&pro_numero=" + vpro_numero + "&exp_requisitante=" + vexp_requisitante + "&exp_num_req=" + vexp_num_req + "&lic_id=" + vlic_id + "&are_id=" + vare_id + "&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs:ClearSession=true&rs%3aFormat=excel&rc%3aToolbar=False&rc%3aJavaScript=False&rc%3aLinkTarget=_top&rc%3aArea=Params");
    }

</script>"
```

Thank you who tried to help.